# Kill all "workers" on "listener" error (multiprocessing, manager and queue set-up)

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, multiprocessing, queue

I'm using multiprocessing to run `workers` on different files in parallel. `Worker`'s results are put into queue. A `listener` gets the results from the queue and writes them to the file.

Sometimes `listener` might run into errors (of various origins). In this case, the `listener` silently dies, but all other processes continue running (rather surprisingly, `worker` errors causes all processes to terminate).

I would like to stop all processes (`worker`s, `listener`, e.t.c.) when `listener` catches an error. How this can be done?

The scheme of my code is as follows:

```
def worker(file_path, q):
    ## do something
    q.put(1.)
    return True

def listener(q):
    while True:
        m = q.get()
            if m == 'kill':
                break
            else:
                try:
                    # do something and write to file
                except Exception as err:
                    # raise error
                    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
                    raise err.with_traceback(tb)

def main():
    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue(maxsize=3)
    with mp.Pool(5) as pool:
        watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))
        files = ['path_1','path_2','path_3'] 
        jobs = [ pool.apply_async(worker, (p,q,)) for p in files ]
        
        # fire off workers
        for job in jobs: 
            job.get()
        # kill the listener when done
        q.put('kill')

# run
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I tried introducing `event = manager.Event()` and using it as a flag in main():

```
## inside the pool, after starting workers
while True:
    if event.is_set():
        for job in jobs:
            job.terminate()
```

No success. Calling os._exit(1) in `listener` exception block rises broken pipe error, but processes are not killed.

I also tried setting daemon = True,

```
for job in jobs:
    job.daemon = True
```

Did not help.

In fact, to handle `listener` exceptions, I'm using a callable, as required by `apply_async` (so that they are not entirely silenced). This complicates the situation, but not much.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always there are many ways to accomplish what you're after, but I would probably suggest using an `Event` to signal that the processes should quit. I also would not use a `Pool` in this instance, as it only really simplifies things for simple cases where you need something like `map`. More complicated use cases quickly make it easier to just build you own "pool" with the functionality you need.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event
from random import random


def might_fail(a):
    assert(a > .001)

def worker(args_q: Queue, result_q: Queue, do_quit: Event):
    try:
        while not do_quit.is_set():
            args = args_q.get()
            if args is None:
                break
            else:
                # do something
                result_q.put(random())
    finally: #signal that worker is exiting even if exception is raised
        result_q.put(None) #signal listener that worker is exiting

def listener(result_q: Queue, do_quit: Event, n_workers: int):
    n_completed = 0
    while n_workers > 0:
        res = result_q.get()
        if res is None:
            n_workers -= 1
        else:
            n_completed += 1
            try:
                might_fail(res)
            except:
                do_quit.set() #let main continue
                print(n_completed)
                raise #reraise error after we signal others to stop
    do_quit.set() #let main continue
    print(n_completed)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args_q = Queue()
    result_q = Queue()
    do_quit = Event()
    n_workers = 4

    listener_p = Process(target=listener, args=(result_q, do_quit, n_workers))
    listener_p.start()

    for _ in range(n_workers):
        worker_p = Process(target=worker, args=(args_q, result_q, do_quit))
        worker_p.start()

    for _ in range(1000):
        args_q.put("some/file.txt")

    for _ in range(n_workers):
        args_q.put(None)

    do_quit.wait()
    print('done')
```

Comment: This greatly clarifies the structure of the program, thank you! You code is a pleasure to read. Yet it does not solve the problem: `worker` might start working when `do_quit` is False, but upon finishing `do_quit` becomes True. In this cases the worker hangs, as `listener` is dead, and Queue has nowhere to release the result. I saved the `error` without explicitly raising it inside the loop, and raised it outside the loop. This worked. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @IvanK. The problem you describe is actually one of the edge cases that `Pool` considers, and has cleanup code to purge queues as part of the shutdown process of the pool. I didn't include that in my example to keep it short.. If you are okay with the "kill it with fire" approach, you can `.terminate()` all workers and `.cancel_join_thread()` all queues from the main process as soon as `do_quit.wait()` returns. The only problem with this is that `terminate` can preempt any buffered stdout or stderr data from the child processes, which in my case caused the exception to not always print.

Comment: That's also a great example of why it's a good idea to add timeouts to `put` and `get` whenever possible, but again this does lengthen the example a bit